# Which scientist had hard time shortening his paper?

Tags: biographical-details, anecdote

A couple of years ago I read an anecdote (amounting to a few sentences, very similar to this very paragraph) about a prominent scientist (most likely a mathematician or a physicist) who submitted a paper for publication and was asked by the editor to shorten it. He returned the paper with minimal changes (something like removing a single 'that', 'and' or a similar insignificant word or even just a comma). The paper seems to have been published without further questions asked.

Last year my friend told me that anecdote as if it had happened to Oliver Heaviside at which point I vaguely recalled that I had read a similar story about someone else. However I failed to look it up in the books as well as to find it via internet search engines and started wondering if my recollection was merely a memory illusion. That's why I am posting this question on this site (which seems to be the most appropriate place for such an inquiry across the StackExchange network).

Comment: If this anecdote has a factual background, Heaviside (or anybody of that generation) seems like an unlikely protagonist. Judging by the average length of publications in the 19th century, they seem to be considerably lengthier than modern publications in the same field, leading me to believe that editorial requests to shorten publications were uncommon in those days. Nonetheless I spent some time searching for Heaviside specifically and came up empty-handed.